# Mutual friendship and pointers: What Pattern or anti-pattern is this?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, refactoring, class-design, friend

In studying the C++ source of a massive app, I find this pattern (the syntax for the example may be sketchy, but the essential details are there):

```
class A  :  X
   friend B;
   B *parent;
   ...stuff...

class B  : Y
   friend A;
   A *myhelper;
   ...stuff...
```

Perhaps it is meaningful that class B is really named AHelper, but I'm more curious about this fairly symmetrical relation between two classes.   Is this part of one of the standard GoF patterns, or an established anti-pattern?  Is there some concept or way of understanding this besides the details, a whole greater than the parts?

Would it make sense to combine A and B into one class?  There is the matter of each class being inherited from other classes X, Y.  I am eager to refactor this code to make it more maintainable and smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what the classes are doing. If it's something like the iterator pattern (i.e. `std::vector<t>` and `std::vector<t>::iterator`), then it can be used for something good.

On the other hand, if the classes are doing fundamentally different things, it's probably best if they are only exposed to each other using their public interfaces.

In other words, I don't think it's a pattern or anti-pattern -- it depends entirely upon the use of the actual classes in question.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are tightly coupled but their lifetimes may be different. It might be worth making into one class if:

- A and B have the same lifetime so one always exists together with the other.
- There is always one A instance for each B instance and vice versa.

It could however be that this is not the case.

Given that A derives from X and B derives from Y, when I have had jointly-coupled classes it is normally the base classes that are coupled, and each class does not interact with the actual concrete class of the other.

In those cases it was not a single lifetime relationship, actually I have one master object that creates and loads smaller objects which go back to the master for more information.

I don't know if the pattern has a name. I have never been hot on design pattern names.